# Sudden occurence of System.TypeInitializationException, no errors are pointed out by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, exception

After working with a Forms Application for basically the whole day, I've created a simple UI and some keydown events. Great! But now, I go to run it, and it suddenly starts throwing a System.TypeInitializationException. Normally, I could probably figure out an issue like this on my own (with Visual Studio's help), however Visual Studio isn't picking up any errors with my coding.

Here is my Form1.cs:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        Shown += new EventHandler(FormShow);
        KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form1_KeyDown);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // ------------------------------- //
    // --------- Game Code ----------- //
    // ------------------------------- //

    public void FormShow(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        GameState = 0;
        //Begin HUDRendererThread
        StartHUDRenderThread(this);
        GameState = 2;
    }

    // ------------------------------- //
    // -- Methods Used By This File -- //
    // ------------------------------- //

    public void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.H)
        {
            DamagePlayer(ThePlayer, 5);
        }
    }

    public void DamagePlayer(Player playa, int damage)
    {
        playa.playerHP = playa.playerHP - damage;
    }

    // ------------------------------- //
    // ----- HUD Renderer Thread ----- //
    // ------------------------------- //

    public class ThreadForRenderingHUD
    {
        public Form from;

        public GameHUD initRenderHUD(Player playerUsed, string desiredName)
        {
            GameHUD newHUD = new GameHUD();
            newHUD.Name = desiredName;
            newHUD.playerToGetStatisticsFrom = playerUsed;
            return newHUD;
        }

        public void GetSettedHP(GameHUD gamehud)
        {
            if (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP >= (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0.8))
            {
                gamehud.HP = 5;
            }
            if (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP >= (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0.6) & gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP < (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0.8))
            {
                gamehud.HP = 4;
            }
            if (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP >= (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0.4) & gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP < (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0.6))
            {
                gamehud.HP = 3;
            }
            if (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP >= (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0.2) & gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP < (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0.4))
            {
                gamehud.HP = 2;
            }
            if (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP >= (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0) & gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP < (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0.2))
            {
                gamehud.HP = 1;
            }
            if (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHP <= (gamehud.playerToGetStatisticsFrom.playerHPMaxValue * 0))
            {
                gamehud.HP = 0;
            }
        }

        public void RenderHUD()
        {
            Player guy = ThePlayer;
            GameHUD ThisGamesHUD = initRenderHUD(guy, "PrimaryGameHUD");
            guy.playerHP = 100;
            guy.playerHPMaxValue = 100;
            guy.playerName = "The Hero!";
            string HPRepresenterHealthBoxIndex = @"C:\Users\Kent Brown\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\GameTesting\images\HUD\HealthRenderer\";
            PictureBox HPRepresenter = new PictureBox();
            HPRepresenter.AutoSize = true;
            Debug.Print(from.Name);
            from.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { from.Controls.Add(HPRepresenter); }));
            string wait = "nil";
            Debug.Print("GAMESTATE HAS BEEN 2");
            while (GameState == 2)
            {
                // --- HP Renderer --- //
                GetSettedHP(ThisGamesHUD);
                wait = HPRepresenterHealthBoxIndex + Convert.ToString(ThisGamesHUD.HP) + ".png";
                from.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { HPRepresenter.Load(wait); }));

                if (guy.playerHP <= (guy.playerHPMaxValue * 0))
                {
                    Label newLabel = new Label();
                    newLabel.Text = "YOU HAVE DIED...";
                    newLabel.Font = new Font(DeathFontFamily, 24, FontStyle.Regular);
                    from.Invoke(new Action(delegate() { from.Controls.Add(newLabel); }));
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void StartHUDRenderThread(Form frm)
    {
        ThreadForRenderingHUD HUDRenderer = new ThreadForRenderingHUD();
        HUDRenderer.from = frm;
        Thread RenderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HUDRenderer.RenderHUD));
        RenderThread.Start();
        while (!RenderThread.IsAlive) ;
    }

    // ------------------------------- //
    // -- Classes(Players/HUD, etc) -- //
    // ------------------------------- //

    public class GameHUD
    {
        public int HP;
        public string Name;
        public Player playerToGetStatisticsFrom;
    }

    public class Player
    {
        public int playerHP;
        public int playerHPMaxValue;
        public string playerName;
    }

    public static FontFamily DeathFontFamily = new FontFamily("Chiller");

    // ------------------------------- //
    // ------ Stuff Declaration ------ //
    // ------------------------------- //

    public static Player ThePlayer = new Player();
    public static int GameState;
    // GameState value references: 0) Initializing 1) Initialized 2) Playing //'
```

And when Visual Studio throws me the exception, it highlights these three lines in the Program.cs:

```
        Application.Run(new Form1());
```

It's giving the exception, shouldn't Visual Studio pick out the cause? If anyone can find the root of the problem, It would be great if you could point it out. Thanks!

Comment: Considering you are getting a specific error, are you also able to get the stack trace?

Comment: When you say, it's "giving the exception", is it just highlighting the `Application.Run` line and showing the exception dialog window callout thing?

Comment: Yes, thats the only thing it does. I have no options to get any sort of error log from it, sadly.

Comment: In that dialog, there should be portion on the view called "Stack Trace".  If you can copy the contents of that value, that may be helpful.

Comment: I'm not seeing any of that. The only options I have when I get the exception window are Break and Continue.

Comment: Can you change your code to look like this, and see which line is throwing the error: `var form = new Form1(); Application.Run(form);`  After that, I would suggest setting a breakpoint and debugging into the application to find out exactly where the issue is.  (Also, are you using the app.config for anything?)

Comment: What is the purpose of `while (!RenderThread.IsAlive) ;`?  You shouldn't have a while loop like the on the UI thread.

Comment: @Gjeltema, var form = new Form1(); is throwing the error. Can I assume from this that there is an error in my form? As for the app.config, I haven't modified it in any way. It still has the same code as when it was created.

Comment: Also, you have the Thread in a method-local variable, surely you want to keep it until the application exits.  Put it in a member variable of your Form and mark it as a background thread.

Comment: @ApachePilotMPE Yes, there's definitely something not initializing right in your Form1.  Whatever it is, it's not shown in the code you've pasted above - I just copy-pasted that code into a fresh winform project, and it created the Form1 fine.  What other members do you have?  Especially `static` items.  Do you have a static constructor?

Comment: @Gjeltema, just figured out the problem. The code works fine now. The problem was that I had a static FontFamily that was being declared outside of the class it was being used in. Thanks for tipping me off about static objects!

Comment: @ApachePilotMPE and there is another static Player instant

Comment: @ApachePilotMPE Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for `static` member initialization.